# How to Set Slider Value Correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my solution I would like to set the value of a slider when the page is navigated to, and save that setting when the user leaves the page. For some reason, my saved slider value is always overwritten to be at the starting value? The ValueChanged event of the slider runs before OnNavigatedTo and resets my saved variable with the user's requested slider value.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Slider x:Name="Slider" Minimum="1" Maximum="256" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged"/>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Slider.Value = (double)Settings.Slider.Value;
    }

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Slider slider = sender as Slider;

        if (slider != null)
        {
            //slider.Value = Math.Round(slider.Value); //Round the value so it is a whole number even when the slider is dragged
            slider.Value = Settings.Slider.Value;
            Settings.Slider.Value = (int)slider.Value;
        }
    }
```

To note, `Settings.Slider.Value` allows the slider value to be saved in storage for future use. I know this works correctly, but I am having trouble ensuring that the slider is always set to the user's preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to set the value of a slider when the page is navigated to, and save
>   that setting when the user leaves the page.

Why not just use `OnNavigatedTo` / `OnNavigatedFrom` combination and leave the `Slider_ValueChanged` alone?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // reload the slider value
    slider.Value = Settings.Slider.Value;

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // save the slider value before exiting
    Settings.Slider.Value = (int)slider.Value;

    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}

private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
     // leave this alone unless the slider actually does something like changing the Opacity of an Image object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Slider_ValueChanged, whenever the value changes, you set the slider.value to old value in settings, and update Settings.Sliver with slider.Value(which you just overwritten in previous line)

```
slider.Value = Settings.Slider.Value;
Settings.Slider.Value = (int)slider.Value;
```

Also, instead of reading and setting value onNavigated, prefer to set them on Loaded event.

```
   Slider.Value = (double)Settings.Slider.Value;
```